# Remove file association for folders

Tags: macos, finder, folders

So, I'm developing software, where I organize code in different folders.

I got a folder named `Company.Software.Logic`.

This is used on different OSes (developer chooses him/herself).

But beeing on Mac, this causes a problem. It says my folder is a "Logic Pro-project".

I do not have Logic Pro installed, and I don't intend to ever install it.
I want my folders to be treated like folder, not application specific files.

Anyone know how to turn this "feature" off?

Renaming folders is a NO GO option.

Comment: Honestly, I would start to think about ways to use a different name :-)

Comment: Honestly. Thats a NO GO. This is a common way to organize code. And it's a standard among the company.

Comment: I understand this. The question has a certain "what happens if an unstopable object hits an unmoveable body" vibe though. Also some of my developer friends consider software which relies on hardcoded paths to be broken by design. So there are several ways out of this at the end :-)

Comment: Well, let's just say that something I learned while developing software for the last 30+ years is that it rarely is worthwile to fight against constraints put out by the OS.

Comment: Those 30+ years should have thought you about the difference between folder structure on disk and the compiled binary.  And since this is being an OS independent application (well.. at least the big 3), and MacOS is the only one having an issue with this folder naming convention. It's just plain dumb approach to consider a folder as some kind of file extension.

Comment: I might agree that using suffixes to identify "special" folders has its drawbacks and may not have been the best design decision somebody made when macOS was born. OTOH I 'm quite sure that personal attacks won't help :-)

Comment: Sorry. Got a bit frustrated about your first comment, when I stated that it was a no go. I've calmed down now.

Comment: RE: "Logic Pro-project" and "I do not have Logic Pro installed" -- Just a point of order... I'm not seeing it show as a "Logic Pro" project. I'm seeing the  **.logic** extension registered to **Garage Band** according to the **Launch Services** database and its icon even has a piano type keyboard in its icon. Note that I'm seeing this on **macOS Catalina** which has **Garage Band** installed.  On **macOS Big Sur** without **Garage Band** installed **Company.Software.Logic** just shows as a normal _folder_.

Comment: No hard feelings, we all get carried away sometimes. And I might have been a bit more diplomatic with that first statement

Comment: @user3439894 Strange. I get "Logic Pro Project" on Big Sur with GarageBand installed. Removing GB doesn't change things.

Comment: @nohillside, After removing **Garage Band**, did you try rebuilding the **Launch Services** database from **Terminal** using on **macOS Big Sur** e.g. `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user`  -- If not could your try and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: @user3439894 Indeed. Rebuilding Launch Services turns the .logic file/folder into standard things

Comment: @nohillside, On **macOS Catalina**, without deleting **GarageBand** and running `/S*/L*/F*/C*/F*/L*/S*/lsregister -u /Applications/GarageBand.app; killall Finder` in **Terminal**, it turned the **Company.Software.Logic** back to a normal _folder_. Although I suspect it may turn back into a _document bundle_ if the **Launch Services** database gets refreshed/updated unless I was to delete **GarageBand**, I'll see.

Comment: For me it's associated with QuickTime. I'll try your voodoo command an hope that will solve it @user3439894. No go for me. And can't delete QuickTime :-S Any magic for that? How did you find all this information? Notice: My Mac is setup as a brand new Mac for Big Sur. No 10.x -> 10.y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the association of an extension using RCDefaultApp. However, it is no longer supported & in the past year the original site has vanished. It was already ancient, but has worked since about 2004 without change.
It does still work for certain in Mojave, possibly Catalina, but as far as I'm aware, not Big Sur.

You can get it from file sites like CNet, MacUpdate, Softpedia etc

There's a modern replacement for RCDefaultApp called [SwiftDefaultApps](https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps) but it doesn't do Extensions.

tbh, your choice of extension was unfortunate. Macs reserve certain extensions to make into virtual packages; Logic is one of them. It doesn't rely on you having the app installed, it's right down at system level, as a known extension.  In effect it's the same as calling a folder `company.project.app` or `company.project.zip` & wondering why it misbehaves.

As a workaround you could right-click > Show Package Contents, but you'd have to do this every time.

Comment: I played around with SDA pref. and found com.apple.logicx.project and 
com.apple.logic.project. Trying "do nothing" didn't help, and there is no way to change it to "open in finder". It sets "ThisAppDoesNothing" as an option for default application.

Comment: As I said, SDA doesn't handle extensions, only RCDefApp can do that

Comment: Crap! The terminal sees the folder as a folder. So MacOS (finder?) treating it differently is just weird. A .zip is a file extension with a header signature, so why MacOS treats a folder.zip as an actuall zip file is just... dumb. A folder should be a folder. A file should be a file. I'll mark your answer as correct, as it states that it can't be done for the time beeing.

Comment: It can be done, withRCDefaultApp. I'd still suggest not using reserved names, though. an App is a folder that Finder treats as a file too. There are many of these reserved names.

Comment: The workaround works in Finder and some apps... Thanks for your help tho! One could argue about a "extension" is consider as a project file when you not even got that application even installed :-( I'll look into RCDA and see if there is any source code or something out in the wild.

Comment: @DannyThunder What if your app tried to claim the .logic file type? You would be hurting all your customers that happen to use logic, but it would save you changing your code base and save time for your users that also don’t care about logic folders or files.

Comment: @bmike You are talking about file types, I'm talking about folders. Two different things. And no. The customers wont get "hurt". Those folders will not be there when the software is compiled. It's for organizing and structuring code. This has NOTHING to do with anything else than a folder being treated as a file extension (which no other OS does).

Comment: The only “hurt” is if they expect the OS to behave like it was designed to work. Sorry I can’t be of more help to you - sounds like you know the challenge to get Apple to change what they did to suit app launching according to how windows does it.

Comment: They won't notice it. Since they don't have to go into folders from finder. It'll be all compile into an application where the folder structure won't exist (even if it did, it wouldn't matter, since it's only finder that is the problem here). The only one facing this is the developers who uses MacOS, might not be a "biggie" for the 99.999999999% MacOS users, but it is to me :)